# How can I implement threads in this scenario?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I haven't got any code at the moment but I have a situation where I will be implementing an Java application onto a wireless sensor. There can only be one *main* method.

There will be multiple other wireless sensors that can connect to my sensor. My sensor needs to do a calculation based on thhe information provided to me by the other sensors. Each sensor can choose whether or not they want to participate in the calculation. Every 1 second, my sensor does a calculation.

So basically, what I need is to listen for incoming sensors, provide them with a thread to interact with, and retrieve the information from each sensor.

My question is, in my application, how do I listen for incoming sensors (blocking call) and also free my application to carry out its calculations?

Comment: You're describing a multithreaded server that listens for connections.  See the bottom of [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html) for a tutorial.

Comment: Hi @AdamMihalcin. Thansk for your reply. So in the 'KKMultiServer' class they have a while loop which is blocking and waiting for a socket connection. This is similar to what I want. However, that class can only accept incoming connections and nothing else. My problem is that I need to do other calculations whilst also waiting for sensors to communicate. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Run another thread for the calculations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a high level, this is what your application will do

==Main Thread==

1. start socket
2. Start processing thread
3. accept an incoming connection (this will cause the thread to block until a connection occurs)
4. start new thread to handle socket (handler thread) (alternatively use a thread pool, but that is more complicated)
5. return to 3

==Handler Thread==

1. Receive open socket from main thread
2. Save data coming in from socket to be given to processing thread
3. Finish and close socket

==Processing Thread==

1. Wait 1 second
2. Process data retrieved from step 2 of Handler Thread
3. Return to 1

Comment: Thanks for your time in constructing your answer. That seems to be a logical solution. I will investigate this implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You need another thread that receives the information of all the communication threads. You should look at the utilities in java.util.concurrent such a BlockingQueue that let threads pass data to one another thread-safely.

Most of all you should read a lot about multi-threading: it is not a trivial topic.

Comment: You're right. I'm not new to Java but I'm not too familiar with multi-threading. I've seen a few things about the BlockingQueue but thought maybe I could make use of the `wait()`and `notify()` functions.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you started.  Add error/exception checking/handling as necessary.

```
public class Test { 
  static class WorkTask42 implements Runnable { 
    public void run() { 
       // background work            
    } 
  } 
  public static void main(String... args) throws Exception { 
    // repeat for each background task
    WorkTask42 wt = new WorkTask42();  
    Thread a = new Thread(wt);  
    a.setDeamon(true);
    a.start(); 
  } 
}
```